# Was wood used in the construction of the TU-144?

Tags: aerospace-materials, plane-construction, tu-144

This image the Yegoryevsk crash of the TU-144 CCCP-77111 appears to show a part of the wreck made of wood:
[image: picture of a part of the wreck]
([picture source](https://englishrussia.com/images/newpictures/Tu-144-crashed-in-France-in-1973/77102-1973-boom-02_full.jpg))

The inside looks like wood slats with rafters. Wood is sometimes used in airplane construction and has pretty good constructive properties, so I don't want to dismiss the idea *a priori* as crazy. Was it the case?

Comment: sure, it is brownish, but that looks like standard metal construction to me

Comment: Surely it was used in constructing the airplane - where do you think they got (some of) their jigs, stands, workbenches, manufacturing building, etc. etc. from?

Comment: Wikipedia has a brief [note on the crash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-144#Yegoryevsk_crash) in [Yegoryevsk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yegoryevsk). That photo looked so much like France in the 70s I was fooled for a moment.

Answer (score 28):

You're looking at a typical metal wing's innards with stringers (small lateral stiffeners made from aluminum angle) riveted to aluminum sheet, and the remnants of wing ribs also attached.  The colour is zinc-chromate primer which ranges in colour from bright green (epoxy zinc chromate), to olive drab, to, that that case, yellow/brown.

There is no wood there.  If any wood can be found in an airplane like the  TU-144, it will be in the interior finishings or panels, or possibly internal bits or fittings that are usually made from plastic, say like a saddle that holds some kind of cylinder in place (in lieu of a plastic or rubber material).  But as far as that picture is concerned, you are definetely looking at metal.